# Zabbix backslash in windows path

Tags: zabbix

I created a discovery rules that returns to Zabbix a list of files (from a Windows VM) in JSON format. Zabbix server accepts the list, but the first chapter after the `\` is deleted:

For example:

```
"C:\User\myuser\Documents"
```

became

```
"C:seryuserocuments"
```

so.. it's completely useless! Is there some way to keep the original path? How can I resolve this issue?
Thank you!!

[EDIT]
Enable debugLevel 4, I find that the server receives the correct JSON:

```
{"data":[
{"{#PATH}":"C:\Users\myuser\Documents\dir1"},
{"{#PATH}":"C:\Users\myuser\Documents\dir2"},
{"{#PATH}":"C:\Users\myuser\Documents\dir3"}
]}
```

Also, I try to escape backslashes in JSON properly: adding `\\\\`, but it doesn't works and the server receives the same list above.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
[/EDIT]

Comment: That's quite unlikely. If you enable DebugLevel 4 for the trapper processes on the server, what's the JSON that the server receives? It seems more likely that your script loses those characters somehow.

Comment: Also, make sure that your script escapes backslashes in JSON properly.